# PHP preg_match two values how to check with || operator

Tags: php, preg-match

I need to check if string contains F: # { blabla } or # F: { blabla } how to do that with preg_match? I try with this code but it does not run code when i add # before letter F:

```
if (preg_match('/F: ([A-za-z0-9]+) ([A-za-z0-9]+)( # (\{.*?\})){0,1}/', $line, $match) || preg_match('/# F: ([A-za-z0-9]+) ([A-za-z0-9]+)( # (\{.*?\})){0,1}/', $line, $match)) {
    echo 'STRING Contains F: and # F:';
}
```

Here is example:

```
<?php
$line = 'F: bbb bbb # { startdate=2015-08-10 | enddate=2015-11-10 | info=info | dealer=person548 | test=0 | emu=unknown | free=0 }';
/* $line = '# F: bbb bbb # { startdate=2015-08-10 | enddate=2015-11-10 | info=info | dealer=person548 | test=0 | emu=unknown | free=0 }'; */
if (preg_match('/(# )?F: ([A-za-z0-9]+) ([A-za-z0-9]+)( # (\{.*?\})){0,1}/', $line, $match)) {
    echo 'STRING Contains F: and # F:';
}
```

Comment: why two different regexes? why not just `/(# )?F` in a single regex?

Comment: Good idea...but when i insert '/(# )?F: ([A-za-z0-9]+) ([A-za-z0-9]+)( # (\{.*?\})){0,1}/' i get error in my datatables....first preg_match works excellent..do you have example code what it needs to be written?

Comment: Can you post some sample string inputs

Comment: I added example in my edit post above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern should look like this:

```
$pattern = '/(F: #|# F:) \{ blabla \}/';
```

Note the capturing ground `(F: #|# F:)`. It matches one of the patterns separated by the `|`.

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/yH3nW3/1)

Comment: Thanks but please take example line from above...i have regex that sort out from string startdate enddate info.... so i need to detect F: and # F: here is example line you could test...for this example line i need regex:  $line = 'F: bbb bbb # { startdate=2015-08-10 | enddate=2015-11-10 | info=info | dealer=person548 | test=0 | emu=unknown | free=0 }';

Comment: Here is demo example live link that i need preg_match you see it only matched first string with F: and need to match # F: so both string need to match...could you please correct regex in example? I im not very familiar with preg_match function...here is link: https://regex101.com/r/yH3nW3/3

Comment: What prevents you from getting familiar with it? Check this: https://regex101.com/r/yH3nW3/4

Comment: Excellent..now it works but i need in matcg[] array like in this example link to finish this...your code is working excellent for # F: anf F: just to put in array items in {} and will be great...link: https://regex101.com/r/yH3nW3/5

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but I'm not your personal coding guard. I gave you some help - and answered the question, now it is up to you to solve the remaining problems.

Comment: Thanks...for you help:) I will mark answer correct because your code works..thanks and have a good day:)

Comment: You are welcome. You'll see, solving problems on your own brings much more benefit. Once you've solved it, you have one trick more in your treasure chest.

Comment: Btw, http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php is one of the best regex manuals I've ever seen. Go through it! But still have patience. Mastering regexes might take some time.

Comment: I know...its ok...i im now tray with errors to have # { startdate=2015-08-10 | enddate=2015-11-10 | info=info | dealer=blabla | test=0 | emu=cccamd | free=0 } to put values in array...( # (\{.*?\})) but it is not working...can you give me hint to get to the point how you can get values from after = to array? If you have time to explain:) Thanks

Comment: you'll find this out yourself.